# Codeigniter 4 Cannot declare class App\Controllers\User_Public\Home, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, codeigniter, namespaces, codeigniter-4

I have searched stackoverflow and indeed there are a lot of questions with this error but for the life of me I cannot see what I am doing wrong.  Here is my routes file;

```
$routes->get('/', '/User_Public/Home::index');
$routes->get('about-us', '/User_Public/Home::aboutUs');
$routes->get('contact-us', '/User_Public/Home::contactUs');
```

Here is my directory structure:

[image: controller subfolder dir structure in codeigniter]

and this is the content of App/Controllers/User_Public/Home
<?php

```
namespace App\Controllers\User_Public;

use App\Controllers\User_PublicController;
use App\Models\UserModel;

class Home extends User_PublicController
{

public function __construct()
{
    // run the parent's contruct
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    //$this->cachePage(DAY);
    // .= will add to exisiting css files.
    $this->data['user_public_css']  .=   '<!-- user_public_css extened -->
                                            <link rel="stylesheet" 
                      href="'.base_url().'/user_public/theme/bs4/css/carousel.css">';
                                            
    $this->data['active_menu']          = '';
    return view('user_public/home/index', $this->data);
}

public function aboutUs()
{
    //$this->cachePage(DAY);
    $this->data['active_menu'] = 'aboutUs';
    return view('user_public/aboutUs/index', $this->data);
}

public function contactUs()
{
    $this->data['active_menu'] = 'contactUs';
    return view('user_public/contactUs/index', $this->data);
}

}
```

This is the error;

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class 
App\Controllers\User_Public\Home, because 
the name is already in use in/var/www/XXXXXXXdomain/api.example.com/app_dir/app/Controllers/User_Public/Home.php on line 0
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: It's most likely because one of your files under the `app` directory other than `app/Controllers/User_Public/Home.php` has a `class` labelled `Home` under the namespace `namespace App\Controllers\User_Public;` Try searching for files that have this namespace in their file contents.

Comment: There is no other class using Home method anywhere

Comment: That's not what I was referring to. *Try searching for files that have this namespace in their file contents.*

Comment: what output do you get when you run: `grep -riF "namespace App\Controllers\User_Public" .` in your project directory?

Comment: In addition, what output do you also get when you run: `grep -riF "class Home" .` in your project directory?

Answer (score 0):

Check Controller "App\Controllers\User_PublicController"
to see whether its extending any controller named "Home" or check whether the Base Controller do extend any controller named "Home"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).